# Time.Scale and RangeBand in Barchart with D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a data source like :

```
dateRange = [
 { date: 2017-03-23, value: 10 },
 { date: 2017-03-25, value: 15 },
 { date: 2017-04-01, value: 13 },
 { date: 2017-04-02, value: 19 }
];
```

Results is like this : https://embed.plnkr.co/iOBAuCZmoMePL5P3Jwr4/

I'd like to generate a barchart with an x axis that covers the whole date range ( from 23 of march to 2 of april in that case ).
Therefore, every single day between these two dates should appears on the x axis ( and set to 0 ).

I don't want to modify the data source. I know d3 can do that for me with d3.time.scale. As rangeBand is not available while using d3.time.scale, i can't find a way to set the correct barchart width.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an ordinal scale, you just need to create an array with all the dates, from the start date to the end date:

```
var dateArray = d3.time.days(d3.min(dataset, function(d) {
    return d.date
}), d3.time.day.offset(d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
    return d.date
}), +1));
```

And use that array for your domain.

Notice that, since the last value in `d3.time.days` is not inclusive, I had to use an `offset` to add an extra day to the end date.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margin = {
     top: 20,
     right: 0,
     bottom: 21,
     left: 30
   },
   height = 300,
   width = 400,
   w = width - margin.left - margin.right,
   h = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

 dataset = [{
   date: '2017-03-23',
   value: 10
 }, {
   date: '2017-03-25',
   value: 15
 }, {
   date: '2017-04-01',
   value: 13
 }, {
   date: '2017-04-02',
   value: 19
 }];
 dataset.forEach(function(d) {
   d.date = parseDate(d.date);
 });

 var svg = d3.select('body')
   .append('svg')
   .attr("width", '100%')
   .attr("height", '100%')
   .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
   .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform",
     "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 var dateArray = d3.time.days(d3.min(dataset, function(d) {
   return d.date
 }), d3.time.day.offset(d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
   return d.date
 }), +1));

 var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w], .2, .02);
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(x)
   .orient("bottom")
   .tickSize(0)
   .tickPadding(5)
   .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%b"));
 x.domain(dateArray);

 svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis easting")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
   .call(xAxis)
   .selectAll("text")
   .style("text-anchor", "middle");

 var y = d3.scale.linear().range([h, 0]);
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(y)
   .orient("left")
   .ticks(6);
 y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
   return d.value;
 })]);

 svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis northing")
   .call(yAxis)
   .selectAll("line")
   .attr("x2", w)

 svg.selectAll('rect')
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr('width', function(d, i) {
     return x.rangeBand();
   })
   .attr('height', function(d, i) {
     return h - y(d.value);
   })
   .attr('x', function(d, i) {
     return x(d.date);
   })
   .attr('y', function(d, i) {
     return y(d.value);
   })
   .attr('fill', 'blue');
```

```css
.chart {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.axis {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.northing line {
  stroke: #F2F2F2;
}

line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #727272;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #727272;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot. I was trying to fix it by modifying the 'scale' while the solution was in the 'domain' definitions.
Thanks for the explanation too.

Comment: Just for fun and to better understand your code, I recreated your answer in [Observablehq](https://observablehq.com/@adas172002/recreating-so-answer-to-question-time-scale-and-rangeband-i)